# How to remove element of array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array:

Arrays:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => point
        [visibility] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => php_first_table
        [visibility] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => ohz
        [visibility] => 1
    )

)
```

Now i want to find and remove element with `name=ohz`:

```
    for($i=0;$i<count($arrays);$i++){
        if(array_search("ohz",$arrays[$i])){
            unset($arrays[$i]);
        }
    }
    print_r($arrays);
```

output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => point
        [visibility] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => ohz
        [visibility] => 1
    )

)
```

Why `php_first_table` not `ohz` was deleted?

Comment: The code should work fine. Can you provide a complete program that has this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arrays);$i++){
    if($arrays[$i]['name'] == 'ohz')){
        unset($arrays[$i]);
    }
}
print_r($arrays);
```

Answer (score 3):

In PHP there is [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for this:

```
$arrays = array_filter($arrays, function($item)
{
   return !(array_key_exists('name', $item) && $item['name']=='ohz');
});
```

Comment: @Jon I'll check now, thank you (I'm messing this with something else?)

Comment: To be fair, changing the internal array pointer yourself (e.g. by calling `reset` inside the loop) is problematic. But deleting items is OK.

Comment: @Jon You're correct, I missed _array pointer_ (which has nothing to do with this case, obviously). Sorry, better to take rest.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
        $arr_var  = Array
        (
            Array('name' => 'point','visibility' => ''),
            Array('name' => 'php_first_table', 'visibility' => 1),
            Array('name' => 'ohz', 'visibility' => 1)
        );

        foreach($arr_var as $key => $value)
        {
            if($value['name'] == 'ohz'){
                unset($arr_var[$key]);
            }
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($arr_var);
        ?>
```

working fine.

- Thanks